# Importing Gradle multi-project: IntelliJ IDEA does't assign folder categories

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

- I've pulled a Gradle project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework, and imported it into IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2.
- IDE recognizes the Gradle project's modules but doesn't seem to recognize the source root, test, resource directories. Because of that, I can't navigate between declarations; IDE doesn't index the .java, .kt files.
- One solution would be to mark the directories manually, however, because the module's configuration is driven by Gradle I would have to re-mark the directories each time I reimport/refresh the project.

Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: Does the same issue occur with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 release: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html?

Comment: @CrazyCoder With the release, it works. Any idea why 2019 version doesn't set them?

Comment: Not sure, some missing functionality or a bug that is now fixed.